# Gatling for functional tests

Tags: gatling

I am planning to use Gatling for functional tests. I have followed this link: https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/functional_specs/
When I extend 'GatlingHttpFunSpec', can some one give me an example of how to access session variables?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, You probably need this:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.token") saveAs "token"))
  .exec(session => {
    println(session.get("token").as[String])        
    session
  })
```